# Is there a way to force curl to use a specific IP rather than using a DNS lookup?

Tags: php, curl

What I want to do is to send a curl request to example.com but rather than using a DNS lookup I want to specifically send the request to say 1.1.1.1

I want to do this because I want to know for certain which of our servers the request is going to and not be bumped around by a load balancer.

I wonder if there is something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( CURLOPT_URL, 'example.com' );
curl_setopt( CURLOPT_ENDPOINT_IP, '1.1.1.1' ); // <= is there something like this?
```

I'm pretty sure there isn't a mechanism within curl itself to do this, but **how could I achieve this effect?**

The server at the IP itself is running vhosts and so its important that the HTTP request includes a named Host and not an IP, which is why I need to put a named host in the request but attach to it by IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://1.1.1.1/' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: example.com') );
```

The power of HTTP protocol knowledge ;)

Comment: I'd like to note that this does not work 100% for HTTPS connections, since there is another field similar to the Host header during the SSL handshake (SNI, server name indication). That one can be set through `SNI_server_name` for stream contexts - I don't know if it is possible for curl though.